# RELAY_SENDME cell structure

Tags: source-code

i am looking to create a RELAY_SENDME cell but can not find the structure for these in the documentation, does anyone know the format fr these cells

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/blob/HEAD:/tor-spec.txt

Comment: Yeah thanks but sorry i should have added,what is contained in the 'data' section of a relay_sendme